# How to access the max and min value of the y axis in dygraph

Tags: dygraphs

In my graph the valueRange is not set, so the y-axis scale automatically. 
is there a way to get the min and max values of the y-axis?

Answer (score 2):

You want the [`yAxisRange`](http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html#yAxisRange) method. It returns a [low, high] tuple.

Comment: thanks a lot, for the answer and especialy for dygraphs!